# Div rotation problem in IE

Tags: css

Actually i have a div i am rotating it using

```
-moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -khtml-transform: rotate(270deg);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

in firefox chrome and opera it is fine in case of there is a slight problem when the page loads the div appears straight for some time after that it rotates to specified rotation value

Answer (score 0):

Works for me fine in IE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

  <title>Untitled Document</title>

  <style type="text/css">

  #myDiv {

  width:200px;

  height:100px;

  background-color:#000;

  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);

  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);

  -khtml-transform: rotate(270deg);

  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);

  }

  </style>

  </head>
<body>

  <div id="myDiv">&nbsp;</div>

  </body>

  </html>
```

Providing I allow IE to allow ActiveX...

Comment: Actually in my case inside the div there is a ul containing three images which are rotated independently using the same approach but to 90 deg is this what causing the problem

Comment: http://pastebin.com/7PHcWBT7 Everything there seems to be working as it should... Why dont you post some more code and maybe a screengrab of the issue you are having?